# Convert xml containing only specific tags

Tags: xml, linux, bash, awk, sed

I have this xml structure, and I want to convert this xml to another one, but only with some fields. How can i do that directly with xmllint or similar tool? I know that i can do this type of job with some php library to parse xml but I want to avoid that, if possible.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <Entities>
       <Ent_ID>1</Ent_ID>
       <Name>John</Name>
       <Age>15</Age>
    </Entities>
    <Entities>
       <Ent_ID>2</Ent_ID>
       <Name>Pedro</Name>
       <Age>20</Age>
    </Entities>
</data>
```

to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <Entities>
       <Name>John</Name>
    </Entities>
    <Entities>
       <Name>Pedro</Name>
    </Entities>
</data>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use `xmlstarlet`:

```
xmlstarlet ed -d '/data/Entities/*[not(self::Name)]' filename.xml
```

`xmlstarlet ed -d xpath` deletes all nodes from the input XML that fit the XPath expression, which in this case describes all subnodes of `/data/Entities` nodes that are not `Name` nodes.